# Dynamic SQL Execution

Tags: sql-server

Im not able to execute below query.Please help.

```
Declare @i Int
Set @i=1
Exec    ('Create  index  tind'+convert(varchar(20),@i)+  ' on product(qty)')
```

Comment: You are getting an error or something?

Comment: Why create 20 indexes on the same column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have an expression as the EXEC argument. Do the dynamic SQL first

```
Declare @i Int, @sql varchar(1000)
Set @i=1
Set @sql = 'Create index tind'+convert(varchar(20),@i)+ ' on product(qty)'
Exec (@sql)
```